# Production Database Creation / Migration dilemma for ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations, dev-to-production

I have been building my ASP.NET Core MVC web application since last year and there are currently 100 migration files in my project, as the database has evolved along with features and capabilities. My development / test database is obviously in sync with this migration.

Now, the time has come to create a Production environment, and I want to have an empty database with only the table schema. So, I just can't copy my test database to create a production database.

So, the question / dilemma I have regarding creating this Production database is as follows;
  1. I can either create my Production database by running Add-Migration command (for which I need to delete existing migration files from the project), or 
  2. Create table schema in SQL Management Server, and keeping the __EFMigrationsHistory from test database

With [1], I am not sure how I will be able to manage my test database with this same project, going forward.
With [2], I am not sure if there is any drawback.

So, what is the standard or best practice for Production deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can certainly use Visual Studio to create or update database tables, but this would normally just be in your development environment.

If you are worried about the number of migrations you have, you still have the option of starting over by deleting them, and deleting your migration history (and manually deleting your tables and data) and creating a fresh 'Initial create' migration. If you do this you will probably want to export any test or config data first, or make sure you have a way to recreate it.

2. For the staging and production deployments, best to use SQL Server Management Studio to generate a script to build your tables. The database administrator - or you if it's just you - can create the database and run the script to generate the tables.

This is because staging and production environments tend to be more tightly controlled than development, so best to understand the processes that are most appropriate for the environment.

You need to check that your dev and staging/production SQL databases are set at a matching 'compatibility level', and also need to decide whether you need to add any seed or configuration data on create.

In SQL Server Management Studio, select the appropriate option to generate a script for the required tables.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-scripts-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15

You can also use this process to export, and import data - this is ideal for config or test data.

https://dzone.com/articles/generate-database-scripts-with-data-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks! So, few follow up questions I have are; (1) What about the successive database changes after system is LIVE in Production? Do I keep tweaking Production database through SQL Server Management, instead of keeping it in sync with Migration? (2) Reason why I don't want fresh database in dev is, I don't want to lose the data (apart from seed/config data). Isn't it possible to get Migration to zero state, without deleting the database entirely? Say, only by deleting the __EFMigrationsHistory table and Migration files?

Comment: Hi 1. For production, best assume that all changes will need to be scripted (and run by a db admin) as it would be unusual to have Visual Studio connected to your live environment. For subsequent changes you can get EF to create migration scripts for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: 2. For dev, you could always back up your SQL data, which will let you tidy-up your migrations - or keep them as they are if that is a hassle, whichever is easier.